# Как оптимизировать данный код JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, оптимизация

написал код, работает все хорошо, но мне кажется можно было бы куда лучше оптимизировать.

```
const [working, setWorking] = useState(true)
  const workTime = () => {
    const simpleNotWorking = [6, 7]
    const weekendNotWorking = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    const currentDate = new Date()
    const currentTime = currentDate.getHours()
    const currentDay = currentDate.getDay()

    if (currentDay >= 1 && currentDay <= 5) {
      if (simpleNotWorking.includes(currentTime))
        setWorking(false)
    }
    if (currentDay === 6 || currentDay === 7) {
      if (weekendNotWorking.includes(currentTime)) {
        setWorking(false)
      }
    }
  }
```

Суть в следующем, есть ресторан, в будни дни работает с 8 утра до 6 утра следующего дня( по будням лишь 2 часа не работают с 6 утра до 8 )
По выходным работают с ( 11 утра до 6 утра)

Я сделал 2 массива в котором указал в котором ресторан не работает
Так же дни недели получаю через getDay ( 1-7)
И прохожусь обычными проверками

Как можно сократить код?

Comment: Вам надо посетить раздел https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @mepihindeveloper Спасибо)

Comment: 6 утра следующего дня в пятничном расписании это уже суббота. С этим могут быть проблемы.

Comment: Сократить-то можно, но вот так чтобы читаемость и понятность кода не ухудшились - совсем не факт. Если бы мне на ревью пришел вариант `+(currentDay >= 1 && currentDay <= 5)` в серьёзном проекте - я бы сказал это переделывать. Лично меня в теле этой функции беспокоят названия некоторых переменных и "нужно ли учитывать праздничные дни?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

единственное, что приходит в голову:

```
  const [working, setWorking] = useState(true)
  const workTime = () => {
    const notWorking = [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7]]
    const currentDate = new Date()
    const currentTime = currentDate.getHours()
    const currentDay = currentDate.getDay()
    
    if (notWorking[ +(currentDay >= 1 && currentDay <= 5) ].includes(currentTime))
        setWorking(false)
  }
```

P.S. getDay разве не 0 для воскресенья возвращает?

Comment: Насколько я посмотрел, он сегодня возврощает 5, учитывая что сегодня пятница

Comment: @Dan [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay), сегодня пятый день, но воскресенье будет не 7 а 0, можно попробовать так [переписать](https://jsfiddle.net/1kg2xem0/1/)

Comment: @Dan, все верно, но для воскресенья вернет 0.
```let date = new Date(2021, 1, 28);//Sun Feb 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)  
console.log(date.getDay())```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так посмотреть.

```js
 const [working, setWorking] = useState(true)
  const workTime = () => {
    const currentDate = new Date()
    const currentTime = currentDate.getHours()
    const currentDay = currentDate.getDay();
    ([6, 7].includes(currentTime) || ([0,6].includes(currentDay) && [8, 9, 10].includes(currentTime))) && setWorking(false); // смотрим на время [6, 7] закрыто в любой день, а  на выходных смотрим дополнительно на [8, 9, 10] 
  }
```